# React Reducer getting called but not changing the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Ive check if both the action and the reducer are getting called. They both get called but the mapstatetoprops isnt changing the state. Also means that action.tpye is getting change. I dont understand why it wont work and any help is appreciated.

This is my reducer

```
const calling = (state={}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CALLING_USER':
      return {type: action.type, callLoading: true, isCalling: true, friend: action.friendSocket}
    case 'ANSWERING_CALL':
      console.log("ANSWER CALL")
      return {type: action.type, callLoading: true, isCalling: true, friend: action.data.socket, offer: action.data.offer}
    case 'CALL_SUCCESS':
      return {
        isCalling: true,
        callLoading: false
      }
    case 'CALL_ERROR':
      return {
        callLoading: false,
        error: true,
        callErrorText: action.err,
      }
    default:
      return {isCalling: false}
  }
}

export default calling
```

Action

```
export const CALLING_USER = 'CALLING_USER'
function callingUser(friendSocket) {
  return {
    type: CALLING_USER,
    friendSocket
  }
}

export const ANSWERING_CALL = 'ANSWERING_CALL'
function answeringCall(data) {
  return {
    type: ANSWERING_CALL,
    data
  }
}
export const CALL_ERROR = 'CALL_ERROR'
function callError(err) {
  return {
    type: CALL_ERROR,
    err
  }
}

export function callSetup(friendSocket, dispatch) {
  console.log("IS THIS WORKING")
  console.log(dispatch)
  return function(dispatch) {
    console.log(dispatch)
    dispatch(callingUser(friendSocket))
  }
}

export function answerSetup(data) {
  console.log("ANSWER SETUP")
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(answeringCall(data))
  }
}
```

It gets called here

```
import { answerSetup } from './Redux/Actions'
import store from './Redux/store'
import io from "socket.io-client";

export const startGlobalSockets = (mySocket) => {
  mySocket.on("gettingCalled", data => {
    console.log("GETTING CALLED SOCKET", data)
    store.dispatch(answerSetup(data))
  })
}
export default startGlobalSockets
```

It should make this statement true.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.session.user,
  calling: state.calling
})

const isVideo = (this.props.calling.isCalling ?
    <Grid style={{width:"100%", height: "100%"}} item sm={10}>
          <VideoScreen/>
    </Grid> :
    <Grid style={{height: '57em', overflow: 'auto'}} item sm={10}>
      <div className="parent">
          <Post/>
      </div>
    </Grid>)
...
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Home))
```

Comment: You can share also the mapStateToProps function and how you use it. My first guess would be that you've forgotten to use the connect function of react-redux on the component where you use that piece of the state.

Comment: can you share the `mapStateToProp` function as well?

Comment: I added the ```mapStateToProps``` but thats not the case. This works when I call the ```callSetup```. Only difference is ```callSetup``` is getting called by a react component and ```answerCall``` is getting called from an array function

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did not use `connect` as required. You are importing it but I don’t see where you use it. It would help if you’d post the whole code snippet including the use of connect and mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `answerSetup` returns a function which internally calls `answeringCall` instead of object with action type and payload (like `answeringCall`). Unless you have some middlewares like react-thunk which handle functions and you have special logic there, I don't see why not using `answeringCall` directly in your calling component.